# "In their own gesture of preparation" meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following passage is from this book :

" The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren "

> The morning of the day had come.
> **In their own gesture of preparation**, the
> Beckford family along with the Warrens
> drove to a nearby church and attended an
> eight A.M. Mass. They then returned to
> the house at nine and waited for the
> exorcist’s arrival.

So English is not my first language and I don't understand the meaning of that phrase. Does it mean it's something that they do like every week ?
I need a synonym please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, they don't do it weekly. It's a special *showy move* to advertise that they are getting ready for their special 9AM appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beckford family is preparing for the exorcist's arrival. A "gesture" is some action intended for some purpose or to convey some meaning, a "gesture of preparation" is intended to convey that they are getting ready. Here, going to church early is an action intended to prepare the family for the upcoming exorcism. The author refers to it as "their own" gesture, as there's not really a typical way that one prepares for an exorcism, so this action might be unique to this family.

There's no implication that they attend mass weekly, it rather suggests the opposite, that this is a special preparation - regularly attending mass like you've done every other week would probably not be considered a "gesture", the use of that word implies that it is a special action for a specific purpose. The use of the word "gesture" also implies that the action conveys meaning, but not that it's particularly effective at what it's supposed to do. The family goes to church as a means of making an effort to prepare themselves, even though it may or may not actually make the exorcism go any more smoothly.

The sentence could be rewritten with a similar meaning as:

> To give themselves a sense of preparation, the Beckford family along
> with the Warrens drove to a nearby church and attended an eight A.M.
> Mass.